# Using variable name as name of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to accomplish the following:

```
vname = [ 'name1', 'name2']

for i in len(vname):
  vname[i] = {} 
  vname[i]['key1'] = 4*i
```

I expect to create two dictionaries name1 and name2 such that

```
name1['key1'] = 0
name2['key1'] = 4
```

Comment: your list contains strings not dictionaries, when you do `vname[i] = {}` you replace the string with a dictionary so the variables `name1` and `name2` never exist, also I assume you mean to use `4*i` instead of `4*1` since the latter is just `4`.

Comment: corrected the code to 4*i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a *nested dictionary* instead, generating values with the help of [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> {key: {'key1': index * 4} for index, key in enumerate(vname)}
{'name2': {'key1': 4}, 'name1': {'key1': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to dynamically create variables of a certain name, you could add them to the global namespace:

```
>>> vname = [ 'name1', 'name2']
>>> for i in range(len(vname)):
...     globals()[vname[i]] = {}
...     globals()[vname[i]]['key1'] = 4*i
... 
>>> name1
{'key1': 0}
>>> name2
{'key1': 4}
```

However, I have never encountered a situation where this was useful or necessary. If you are trying to sth. like this, you are very likely better off with a different (and better behaved) data structure like the nested `dict` suggested by @alexce.